# Finding all element names with values using xslt coding

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Consider below is my xml and i have to write xslt to produce output in two column table. The first column should contain element name with attribute value and second column should contain node value.

Ex: Program

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xml.xsl"?>
<article>
<front>
    <journal-meta>
        <journal-id journal-id-type="pubmed">Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A</journal-id>
        <journal-id journal-id-type="publisher">PNAS</journal-id>
        <issn>0027-8424</issn>
        <publisher>
            <publisher-name>The National Academy of Sciences</publisher-name>
        </publisher>
    </journal-meta>
    <article-meta>
        <title-group>
            <article-title>The coreceptor mutation</article-title>
        </title-group>
        <contrib-group>
            <contrib contrib-type="author">
                <name>
                    <surname>Sinma</surname>
                    <given-names>Army D.</given-names>
                </name>
            </contrib>
        </contrib-group>
                <p>#x002A; Present address: PMD Centers for Disease Control and Prevention, Portland, OR 97232.</p>
            </fn>
            <corresp id="FN151">#x2020; To whom reprint requests should be addressed. E-mail: <email>kirmanee@ich.edu</email>.</corresp>
            <fn fn-type="com">
                <p>Communicated by avatar Friedman, University of Mann, Minneapolis, MN</p>
            </fn>
        </author-notes>
        <abstract>
            <p>We explore the impact of a host genetic factor on heterosexual HIV epidemics by using a deterministic mathematical model.</p></abstract>
        </article-meta>
    </front>
    <body>
        <p>Nineteen million people have</p>
        <p>To exemplify the contribution</p>
        <sec>
            <title>The Model</title>
            <p>Because we are most concerned </italic>(<italic>t</italic>)#x005D;</p>
    </sec>
</body>
</article>
```

XSLT code tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="article">
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th style="text-align:left">ELEMENT</th>
<th style="text-align:left">VALUE</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="*/*">
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>=> </td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output should be in below format:

```
Element------Value
journal-id journal-id-type="pubmed----Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A
journal-id journal-id-type="publisher"---PNAS
issn----0027-8424
.
.
p------Nineteen million people have
p----To exemplify the contribution
```

> Please help me to get the proper code

Comment: **1.** Please format your question properly. **2.** What if the element has more than one attribute?

Comment: Please explain more about what you tried yourself, what results you achieved and how they differ from the desired result. It seems that you did not provide any of that information. You hence risk the misunderstadning that you just want somebody else to do the work for you. In contrast to that, StackOverflow is meant to help with specific questions on programming problems you encountered when trying to program yourself.

Comment: "fixed grammar" does not seem to describe your edit, which mostly deleted code....

Comment: You seem to not have appreciated my formatting help. So you need to get your question formatted yourself. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks for the questions i included the XSLT code which i have tried,,, in my xml only one attribute should be allowed if second attribute present need to ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML (I am not using yours, because it is not well-formed)**

```
<article>
  <front>
    <journal-meta>
      <journal-id journal-id-type="pubmed">Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A</journal-id>
      <journal-id journal-id-type="publisher">PNAS</journal-id>
      <issn>0027-8424</issn>
      <publisher>
        <publisher-name>The National Academy of Sciences</publisher-name>
      </publisher>
    </journal-meta>
    <article-meta>
      <title-group>
        <article-title>The coreceptor mutation</article-title>
      </title-group>
      <contrib-group>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <name>
            <surname>Sinma</surname>
            <given-names>Army D.</given-names>
          </name>
        </contrib>
      </contrib-group>
      <p>#x002A; Present address: PMD Centers for Disease Control and Prevention, Portland, OR 97232.</p>
      <corresp id="FN151">#x2020; To whom reprint requests should be addressed. E-mail: <email>kirmanee@ich.edu</email>.</corresp>
      <fn fn-type="com">
        <p>Communicated by avatar Friedman, University of Mann, Minneapolis, MN</p>
      </fn>
      <abstract>
        <p>We explore the impact of a host genetic factor on heterosexual HIV epidemics by using a deterministic mathematical model.</p>
      </abstract>
    </article-meta>
  </front>
  <body>
    <p>Nineteen million people have</p>
    <p>To exemplify the contribution</p>
  </body>
</article>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ELEMENT</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//text()">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="attr" select="../@*" />
                    <xsl:if test="$attr">
                        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name($attr)"/>
                        <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$attr"/>
                        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (rendered)**

[image]

Comment: Wavv.. this is what my expected output .. I'm so thankful to you..

Answer (score 1):

If you want your output as only text like what you have shown in your question, you could use this.

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>Element------Value&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(parent::*), '-----', .)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i want the output in table format only..